# Example of a diff returning a file rewrite

Tags: git

In the documentation for [git diff-format](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-format) the following is said regarding in-place edits:

> Status letter M may be followed by a score (denoting the percentage of dissimilarity) for file rewrites.

but no example of what is said is provided.

What are file rewrites and how are they different from file modifications?

Can you provide an example of a diff returning an entry for a file rewrite with some percentage of dissimilarity, like

`:100644 100644 5be4a4a fabadb8 M050 file.c`

where `M050` means 50% dissimilarity?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets follow the [git rewrite test case](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t4022-diff-rewrite.sh) to get a % dissimilarity.

1. Download the sample content from git,
   `wget -O test https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/COPYING`
2. `git add test; git commit -m"initial commit"`
3. Replace few contents of the file,

```
head -230 test | tr "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM" > test.tmp
tail -130 test >> test.tmp
cat test.tmp > test
```

4. `git diff -B --raw test`

```
:100644 100644 536e555 0000000 M063     test
```

5. During commit, the file will be marked as rewrite.

```
git add test
git commit -m"commit 60percent"
[master 59c06d0] commit 60percent
 1 file changed, 360 insertions(+), 360 deletions(-)
 rewrite test (63%)
```

As per [git diff's -B option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Bltngtltmgt), if more than 40% of the file is not changed, it will not be considered a rewrite. You need to pass parameters to git diff to get 50% dissimilarity.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
head -186 test | tr "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM" > test.tmp
tail -174 test >> test.tmp
cat test.tmp > test
```

```
git diff --raw -B/50
:100644 100644 536e555 0000000 M050     test
```

However, while committing the file, it will not be considered a rewrite

```
git add test
git commit -m"commit 50percent"
[master 89aa4a6] commit 50percent
 1 file changed, 177 insertions(+), 177 deletions(-)
```

Comment: I have just discovered that with the `-B` option the status letter `T` (meaning type change) comes with a dissimilarity index in the form `Tnnn`. So far, I have only seen `T100`, even after changing from a symbolic link `file.txt -> f.txt` to the `file.txt` with content `this is f.txt`.

Comment: I have seen the above using git version 2.28.0

Comment: @mljrg, strange that it prints the index for type change. I don't think we will get any value other than 100 for type change. Interstingly there is no documentation mentioning whether it is dissimilarity or similarity index.

Comment: Yes, the documentation says nothing about this. Also, the similarity/dissimilarity values appear always as three digits in the output, and the documentation only shows two digits when they are below 100%. Probably something needs to be fixed, either the code or the docs.